VS2022 Angular project with standalone components - Typescript Linting totally broken
In VS2022 create Angular project.
Convert components to standalone.
Delete NgModule
Bootstrap AppComponent
Add a test component and import into AppComponent.
Problem 1.
VS complains that any new component is not standalone. Standalone is the default for Angular 19. No other configuration should be required.

Problem 2.
If I work around the first probem by adding standalone: true to the component decoration, VS then fails to recognise any inputs for any component.

Problem 3
Since the last update VS is hanging and going unresponsive or sometimes even crashing to desktop opening a solution with an Angular project. Any other project type is no problem.

The ng cli compiles the project with no issues or warnings at all. It's as if VS2022 is using the wrong Javascript/Typescript language service, although I see no way to know what version it's using, let alone how to change it.
VS Code has no issues at all. Lints all projects correctly and does not crash.
Is anyone else have the same issues? Anyone got any ideas how to fix?

Angular language service - visual studio guide

The problem is that Microsoft haven't updated the Angular Language Service in years so at this point it's broken in Visual Studio.
This Github issue and the ones it links to describe the issues, and there is a partial workaround.
Given how much we pay for our Visual Studio licences this is a really good example of how that is starting to seem like a total waste of money.
